# How do I make a horizontal Scrollbar at the top of the div Work after the content has been loaded via ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

**HTML CODE**

```
   <div  id="scrollidout"  style="overflow: auto; overflow-y: hidden; ">
    <div id="scrollidin" style="padding-top: 1px; height: 20px; width: 1000px">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
<div class="resultcontent" style="overflow: auto; overflow-y: hidden; " id="resultcontent" >

  SEARCH RESULTS HERE

  <div id="scrollidin12" style="padding-top: 1px; height: 190px; width: 3200px">
    klklklklkklklklklkklklklklkklklklklkklklklklkklklklklkklklklklkklklklklkklklklklkklklklklkklklklklkklklklklkklklklklkklklklklkklklklklkklklklklkklklklklkklklklklkklklklklkklklklklkklklklklkklklklklkklklklklkklklklklkklklklklkklk
    lklklkklklklklkklklklklkklklklklkklklklklkklklklklkklklklklkklklklklkklklklklkklklklklkklklklklkklklklklkklklklklkklklklklkklklklklkklklklklkklklklklkklklklklkklklklklkklklklklkklklklklkklklklklkklklklklkklklklklkklklklklkklklklklkklklklklkklklklklkklklklklkklklklklkklklklklk
  </div>

</div>
```

**JAVASCRIPT CODE**

```
 $(function(){


   $('#scrollidout').on('scroll', function(){
        $('#resultcontent')
            .scrollLeft($('#scrollidout').scrollLeft());
    });

    $('#resultcontent').on('scroll', function(){
        $('#scrollidout')
            .scrollLeft($('#resultcontent').scrollLeft());
    });
  });
```

When Loaded At first It works when the entire page works
But When the I Change the Contents of the div "#resultcontent" using Ajax, I cannot use the top scrollbar to scroll the div again. How can I Solve This?

Answer (score 0):

Does it helps you ? https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/CSS/overflow

Put a class with `overflow : scroll` to force the scroll bar to appear.

Comment: I just did that. But it is still functionally the same as auto. Everything works when entire page is loaded but when i change the contents i.e replacing the div element below with a table. the top scrollbar stops working. Only the bottom or default works. I just want both to work. In this case Focusing on the Top Scrollbar. Thanks
 <div id="scrollidin12" style="padding-top: 1px; height: 190px; width: 3200px">kkk...</div>